# iOS 9: How to disable Location Services for specific apps?

Tags: ios, geolocation

It used to be obvious how to enable or disable Location Services on an individual app basis, but today when trying to do this on an iPad running iOS 9 I didn't see any way to do this.

Has the feature been removed, leaving me no other way than to disable Location Services entirely? I just want to keep my photos from being geotagged. I still want to find my current location on maps and use other such features.

All the web searches I've done so far yield outdated how-to pages showing old methods.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can still do that.
All you have to do is:

- Opening **Settings** > **Privacy** > **Location services**

Now here you can either **disable/enable** completely the location services, or **limit** the access to some of the Apps you choose, it's all up to you.

Thus, if you want to **disable** the **geotagging** in your photos and videos you'll want to **disable** the **Camera** option from this list.

Hope it helped you out!

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. The cause of the confusion was that the Camera app wasn't in the list - because the Camera app *had not yet been used* while Location Services were on. (This is an iPad restored to factory settings, so Camera hadn't been used much) After turning on Location Services, *then* using the Camera app, a pop-up appeared prompting whether to allow access or not. The Camera app then also became visible in that Settings menu. Anyway, thanks for trying to make it more clear.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help somehow :) @Mentalist

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Location Services and then disallow when the app prompts you (when you launch it). After doing this the app will appear in the list so you can turn it on or off.

This is true even for apps that are installed by default.